# fill grid view in c#

Tags: c#, gridview

I am new in using visual studio and ADO.NET. I want to display result from sqlserver database in data gridview.

This is my code but it does not fill data to  gridview.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Expert_person", con);
            con.Open();
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@takhasos", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedText;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();       

            da.Fill(dt);
            SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            this.dataGridView1.Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
```

Comment: Check with my answer and let me know if you got the output or not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you binding to grid two times?

If your application is **ASP.NET Webforms** and you are trying to bind the `GridView`(`ID` for the `GridView` is "`dataGridView1`"), then make your binding to single time and to bind data for GridView you need to use `dataGridView1.DataBind();` after `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

If your application is **WindowsForms** application then modify your code like below

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

    string connectionString = "Define your connection string here";
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString ))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Expert_person", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@takhasos", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedText;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();       
        da.Fill(dt);                   
        this.dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```